# Is this holistic approach, focusing on the relation between speaking and singing, uncommon? If so, why?

Tags: voice

I have taken singing lessons from different teachers . Only one, my current teacher, focuses a lot on my speaking voice. This has helped me a lot. She says that she has learned a lot from actors. The holistic approach: focusing on how speaking and singing are related has helped me a lot.

Is this holistic approach uncommon? If so, why?

Comment: My vocal instructor does the same.  She says my singing voice should be "conversational".  She is classically trained.

Comment: conversational?

Comment: Yes, conversational.  As opposed to belting it out.  Even when singing opera the vocalist should not be pushing hard and the quality of the vocals should be easy, like having a conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Speech level singing" has enough of a practitioner and fan base that a web search for "SLS" turns up, well, not a lot unless you put in a few more search keywords.

However, in singers' circles it is a reasonably well-known method, though it does not as much describe a general technique but a particular voice teacher's method and what some perceive as a well-curated and advertised cult around it.

Now of course talking and singing are related: lyrics *are* words, after all.  And a number of techniques particularly regarding breath and vocal control for efficient and healthy vocalisation apply to either.  However, singing seriously transcends what speaking does with voice, and vocalisation techniques differ significantly with singing styles: a speech-oriented approach is better targeted to things like broadway singing than operatic singing.

So a sensible vocal education should of course exploit commonalities as well as possible (of course we train speaking from early childhood on, but probably not doing it in the most efficient, healthy, and pleasing manner) while not getting stuck on them where they stop making sense.  For example, coloratura sopranos (and also high tenors) need to concern themselves with vowel modification for best effect, something that just does not apply to normal speaking voice.  Also the natural "speech melody" is supplanted when singing.

Comment: You wrote ". Also the natural "speech melody" is supplanted when singing."
Desn't that depend on the melody you sing? Wouldn't at least the accents in speach and singing be the same most of the time?